# Translate Custom Profiles not appearing translated in Drupal

Tags: drupal, profile, user-account, user

When creating a Custom Profile in CiviCRM and attaching that to the Drupal Registration and/or Drupal user account the translations for Portuguese, French, and Spanish are not appearing based on the *Inherit CMS value set*

Answer (score 5):

It took me about a half of a day to debug this thinking it was a bug in Core. In your `civicrm.settings.php` file there is a section that helps properly map Drupal and CiviCRM languages. This is especially important for *Spanish, Portugues, English (Canada), and French (Canadian)*

Edit this file and uncomment the appropriate lines as shown below:

`/**
 * If you have multilingual site and you are using the "inherit CMS language"
 * configuration option, but wish to, for example, use fr_CA instead of the
 * default fr_FR (for French), set one or more of the constants below to an
 * appropriate regional value.
 */
// define('CIVICRM_LANGUAGE_MAPPING_FR', 'fr_CA');
// define('CIVICRM_LANGUAGE_MAPPING_EN', 'en_CA');
// define('CIVICRM_LANGUAGE_MAPPING_ES', 'es_MX');
// define('CIVICRM_LANGUAGE_MAPPING_PT', 'pt_BR');
// define('CIVICRM_LANGUAGE_MAPPING_ZH', 'zh_TW');`

Doing so will immediately map these languages properly in your system and start to render the labels in the languages you have translated.